# laptop fan does not stop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hard-drive, fan

My laptop does not stop spinning its fans after i installed a hdd from a desktop. Here is what happened.

1. I installed windows 7 on the laptop.2
2. I moved laptop hdd to a desktop. Desktop worked without a problem.
3. I then re-moved hdd to the laptop.
4. laptop fans are spinning non-stop now.

I resolved this issue a year ago by installing chipset drivers. I tried that, but it does not work now.

any ideas?

Comment: why did you move your laptop HDD to the desktop?

Comment: You either broke the HDD or didn't reconnect it the right way, did you do something else with the HDD, your laptop or your OS besides moving it?

Comment: @A. Donahue // sorry for the confusion. Actually, it wa sdd. That is why i put it the laptop.

Comment: @TomWij // if I broke the hdd, my laptop would not even boot. They work just fine.

Comment: It could boot perfectly and still have an impact on your laptop, as it's the only thing you have changed it made me think that... Another try: Have you checked the temperatures of your CPU (CoreTemp), your GPU (RivaTuner) and HDD (SpeedFan)?

Comment: @TomWij // temperatures are actually lower than normal hdd on sdd.

Comment: And the CPU and GPU? If one of those has an increase in temperature this might cause the fan to be permanently on... Do the fans also spin when you leave your computer on in the BIOS instead of the Operating System? If it does it's a hardware problem, if it doesn't it might be a driver as you indicated or software problem... Have you checked the CPU usage?

Answer (score 2):

In a year a lot of dust can build up on the filter of the fan.

Changing the harddrive might have led to an increase in the internal temperature crossing a threshold, causing the fan to stay on.

Or as you say, it could be driver related. I had that problem with ubuntu until I installed proper drivers for my graphics card.

Comment: // no...when I switch back to original laptop hdd, it works just fine.

Comment: Is the new harddisk physically bigger, does it use more power, does it block the flow of air?

Comment: new hdd is a ssd. Not bigger, consume less power

Comment: I'm afraid it's back to the drivers then.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem with my HP Compaq nx6325 about one year ago. The solution that worked for me was cleaning the dust out, like bryan said. There was a real big dust bunny occupying space around the cpu cooling devices. After cleaning it, the Fan was nicely silent and only was running if needed.

Comment: // they are clean already.

Answer (score 0):

I had a laptop where sometimes going into windows, that happened.
Not dust. Just some windows setting getting changed.

I ran a program called speedfan, and set the speed from 100% to 0.

This actually had the effect that only when the CPU got over a certain temp, did it go on. Much better.

I Monitored temp too with speedfan, to make sure it was OK. It was.

You could also try fiddling  with power options in control panel.. or something like that. I think the toshiba laptop I had, had options there. But I remember the speedfan solutioh worked for me and should work on any laptop.